# Storing binary bits into an integer array?

Tags: java

Currently, I just have `data` store the length of the bits, which isn't what I'm looking for.I would like to store the bits generated by the `BinaryNumber` constructor into the attribute `private int data[]`.  `data` would later be used for other methods (for retrieving bit length,conversion to decimal, etc.). I am pretty new to Java programming, so I would very much appreciate if you can help me with this problem that I am facing.

```
public class BinaryNumber {

    private int data[]; 
    private boolean overflow; 



    /**
     * Creates a binary number of length length 
     * and consisting only of zeros.
     * 
     * @param Length
     * 
     **/

    public BinaryNumber(int length){
        String binaryNum=" "; 
        for (int i=0; i<length;i++) {
            binaryNum += "0";

        }
        System.out.println(binaryNum);
        data= new int[length];
    }



public static void main (String[] args) { 
        BinaryNumber t1=new BinaryNumber(7);

        System.out.println(t1);
    }
```

For example, the test above should generate seven 0s (0000000) and I would like to store those seven bits into the array `data` instead of what I do in my current code, which is storing it into a String `binaryNum`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Show sample input and output.

Comment: @shmosel edited the description for more clarity.

Comment: You mean like `data[i] = 0`?

Comment: @shmosel yes! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public BinaryNumber(int length) {
    data = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

The Java spec, however, guarantees that all `int` values are initialized with 0, so your constructor could be simplified to just:

```
public BinaryNumber(int length) {
    data = new int[length];
}
```

Comment: To be exact, all _array elements_ (the case here) and also method fields are initialized: number and `char` to 0, `boolean` to `false`, reference to `null`. But _local variables_ of any type (`int` or other) are not initialized unless you write an initializer.